# How to use executor and future

Tags: java, plsql

Hi i am  to 'you' with java so need some help with this code block 
i am calling java code from pl/sql

```
XXX.execute(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.lang.String

public class XXX {


 public static String execute(String executable, String workingdir, String input) {        
      String line = "";

      try {
          Command command = new Command(input, executable, "-a", workingdir + "ndrg.gg");
          command.execute();

          line = command.getErrorOutput();
          if (line.contains("1 records processed")) {
             line = command.getOutput();
             if (line.length() > input.length() + 1) {
                line = command.getOutput().substring(input.length() + 1);
             } else {
                line = "ERROR:1- " + line;
             }
          } else {
             line = "ERROR: " + line; 
          }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          line = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
      };

      return line;
  }
```

}

I need to check if command.execute do not response 10 sec then XXX.execute return a ERROR i read about ExecutorService and Future but ... :(

Comment: What would you like to know exectlly about executor and future? Do you want to wait (block) for the response in 10s?

Comment: I want if the command.execute are longer than 10 sec then need to block (kill) and return line with some Error text for pl/sql

Comment: To be sure, what is Command? I could provide you solution with Callable which execute your task and which will be submited to executor which return Future waiting 10s for response.

Comment: Command is a public class, Yes i want that if command.execute 'process' is longer than 10 sec then some exception and back to pl/sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this way:

- implement [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call%28%29) interface and put your code in *call* method
- submit your task to [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) and get instance of the Future object
- call [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on the Future object. This method will block until response is returned otherwise TimeoutException will be thrown.

Solution:

```
public static String execute(final String executable,
            final String workingdir, final String input) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                // Execution in another thread.
                String line = "";
                try {
                    Command command = new Command(input, executable, "-a",
                            workingdir + "ndrg.gg");
                    command.execute();
                    line = command.getErrorOutput();
                    if (line.contains("1 records processed")) {
                        line = command.getOutput();
                        if (line.length() > input.length() + 1) {
                            line = command.getOutput().substring(
                                    input.length() + 1);
                        } else {
                            line = "ERROR:1- " + line;
                        }
                    } else {
                        line = "ERROR: " + line;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    line = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return line;
            }
        };
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(task);
        String response = "";
        try {
            // Wait 10s for response.
            response = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Write something meaningful
            response = "InterruptedException"
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Write something meaningful
            response = "ExecutionException"
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Do something if response is not ready within 10s.
            response = "TimeoutException"
        }
    return response;
    }
```

Comment: Why here     Future<String> future = executor.submit(task); didnt have a executor.shutdown(); ??? Without shutdown when i runned the code in Pl/sql it was locked with shutdown all is ok. Why there is no future.cancel(true); ?? But really thanks you helped me a lot only need answer for my question ;) for save ...

Comment: As I understood you wanted to do your job within 10s so I didn't use shutdown and future.cancel(true). Your taks is passed to executor which takes care of the execution and future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); wait (block) for the response. I hope that I catch your point :) Let me know

Comment: I needed that if command.execute are not responding  or not returning the result, then after 10 sec all process will be killed and i can return some handled ex to pl/sql.

Comment: So if the method command.execute does not respond future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); throws TimeoutException (if the wait timed out) or ExecutionException (if the computation threw an exception). Is it ok?:)

Comment: Yes it is OK! but now i started to test  the execution of this code is stucking and locking procedures @ DB :(

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer please accept it. If you have any question according to java code please ask. Good luck.

Comment: Code are stucking in this statement    } else {
                        line = "ERROR: " + line;
                    }    but why another thread are not helping to avoid stuck ?  But Good question is this else ....

Comment: The code in call method is executed asynchronusly but the rule for the Future is that you can pass it to another method and check result in future.

Comment: uhh.. but if I wanted only to avoid the stuck ? I got a process that ar e calling this java code(java code as you see executes other app and return some lines) we founded out that this java code ar stucking and locking DB procedures how i can avoid from stuck in this XXX.execute ? THANKS a LOT !

Comment: hmm i thinked out in this case else {
                 line = "ERROR: " + line; 
              } i need to raise  exception and handle it ?

Comment: Check this for more info: http://java.dzone.com/articles/javautilconcurrentfuture or think about RxJava. In my opinion in that situation you have to make some callback (listener) which will notify your code.

Comment: OK Big thanks to you for info only the last question about java how can returm the line and stop the java code : return line; System.exit(0); are not working together :(

Comment: I updated the code. It should stop java code when response is ready or after 10s you receive response (frome the above code): "TimeoutException" or something else.